# Python regex matching 1 or 2 but not 3 of a character

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to match strings containing only 1 occurrence or 2 occurrences but not 3 occurrences of a `-` character in a 3 character sequence. For example the regex should match the following:

```
--A
-A-
A--
-AA
AA-
```

But NOT match:

```
---
```

I am alright with regex, and I have tried `re.search('-{1,2}[^-]','AA-')` but this seems to not work with python. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the characters need be consecutive, or can they be interspersed with each other? Also, I doubt that regular expressions should be used for this.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "interspersed" with each other. The dashes are already interspersed between the characters. But they may also be grouped together as long as there is not three in a row.

Comment: Why is it that I am not able to ask a simple, straightforward question without being repeatedly knocked down. I provided all possible scenarios in which the regex should match and which it should not. What more do you want?

Comment: do you mean three `---` individually or `A---AA`, what is the actual format of your string.

Comment: @E.Cross Wat? Also, do you really need to revenge downvote my answer? That's so immature.

Comment: The format is simply three characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No regex:

```
matches = (1 <= s.count('-') <= 2)
```

Comment: Alternatively if he has more characters than the three (from his question it doesn't seem like it) he could just switch it to something like: `(0 < s.count('A') < 3)`. However +1 for mentioning the string method.

Comment: I like your solution, but unfortunately I was looking to learn a regex solution even if it is not the best way. +1 for the idea though.

Comment: @E.Cross: Find a better problem to apply regex to. If you can apply a simple string operation, you should *always* prefer that.